# how to display individual resolvers within a team on a monthly basis

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, count, distinct, sql-view

I've currently got an SQL view that shows how many members of each team have made a resolution on each day since April 2017 using the below code. How would I amend this so I could do this by month rather than on a daily basis?

```
SELECT CAST(stat_datetimeresolved as date) as DateResolved, ResolvedByTeam, COUNT(DISTINCT resolvedby) as ResolvedByCnt
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
 WHERE Stat_DateTimeResolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY CAST(Stat_DateTimeResolved as DATE), ResolvedByTeam
ORDER BY CAST(stat_datetimeresolved as DATE) asc, ResolvedByTeam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the date to be shown as year and month only:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyyMM')
```

And then group by this value. So your query should become something like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(stat_datetimeresolved, 'yyyyMM') as MonthResolved, ResolvedByTeam, COUNT(DISTINCT resolvedby) as ResolvedByCnt
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
 WHERE Stat_DateTimeResolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY FORMAT(stat_datetimeresolved, 'yyyyMM'), ResolvedByTeam
ORDER BY MonthResolved asc, ResolvedByTeam
```

UPDATE: For pre-2012 versions, the year-month part can be constructed using DATEPART function. In this case the query could look like this:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2) as MonthResolved, ResolvedByTeam, COUNT(DISTINCT resolvedby) as ResolvedByCnt
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
 WHERE stat_datetimeresolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2), ResolvedByTeam
ORDER BY MonthResolved asc, ResolvedByTeam
```

or

```
SELECT convert(char(6), Stat_DateTimeResolved , 112) as MonthResolved, ResolvedByTeam, COUNT(DISTINCT resolvedby) as ResolvedByCnt
FROM [dbo].[Incident]
 WHERE Stat_DateTimeResolved >= '20170401'
GROUP BY convert(char(6), Stat_DateTimeResolved , 112), ResolvedByTeam
ORDER BY MonthResolved asc, ResolvedByTeam
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the FORMAT function that's being used here. That could be because the version I'm currently using is 2008. From looking on various forums, it would appear the FORMAT function became recognisable from 2012 onwards.

Comment: Ah, sorry! You can use DATEPART in this case. Replace it with expression like this: CONCAT(DATEPART(year, stat_datetimeresolved), '-', RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, stat_datetimeresolved) as varchar(2)), 2))

Comment: I'm getting the same message come back as before. CONCAT is not a recognised built-in function name. I've managed to alter the format of the date using - select convert(char(6), getdate(), 112). Just not sure how to incorporate this into my script.

Comment: CONCAT simply concatenates its parameters. You can replace is with + operators. I updated my answer to show the usage of convert too.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Andrey.